# How to use new File() in nodejs

Tags: node.js

How we can use `new File()` in nodejs env, I need to create a new file without saving it any idea? I searched for npm packages but didn't manage to find anything that is good for the case

Comment: `new File()` does not exists in node.js. What are you trying to achieve? Just construct the content of the file and do what ever you want. No need to use `new File()`

Comment: I'm receiving img and i need to compose new file but do not save it on the fs and then send it to third party how to compose this file having the img and not using new File()?

Comment: Compose as/to what? Your question is not clear. Edit it and add all details. Ask for what you need/want. Sounds like a xy problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: Just want to create a file having the image and pass it to 3rd party service that's the goal

Comment: And for what do you need the `File` API again? Just create a buffer/object and do what ever you want... Please read the link i posted.